# How to sort existing DOM elements using a javascript console?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dom

I want to sort some table rows from a webpage using the built-in javascript console in firefox. The website itself doesn't offer alphabetical sorting, but the database is big and i need to find things faster.

The structure is like this:

```
<table id="entries">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img />
            DATA
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</table>
```

So finally i want to reorder those `tr`-elements sorting **DATA** alphabetically

*(Using the Firefox Search doesn't work, because it won't scroll to the position of the word and i need to find multiple items with the same name.)*

Comment: sorting according to which cell? Do you have only a single cell? (`<td>`)

Comment: there are 4 tds but only the DATA after <img> in the first td matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done something different but I really liked the code of @Thomas so that i just wanted to generate a generic `tableSorter` function based on his resolution. This might be quite useful as a callback to table header element click events.

This function takes three arguments;

1. the table object
2. the cell (column) index to sort upon
3. if `true` ascending else descending

```js
function tableSorter(table,cellIndex,order){ // table object, cell index and order passed as arguments
  var frag = [...table.rows].map(row              => ({tr: row, data: row.cells[cellIndex].textContent.trim()}))
                            .sort((a,b)           => order ? a.data.localeCompare(b.data) : b.data.localeCompare(a.data))
                            .reduce((frag,sorted) => (frag.appendChild(sorted.tr), frag),document.createDocumentFragment());
  window.requestAnimationFrame(table.appendChild.bind(table,frag));
  return table;
}
var myTable = document.getElementById("entries");
tableSorter(myTable,0,true);
```

```html
<table id="entries">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img /> XDATA
    </td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>w</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img /> ADATA
    </td>
    <td>p</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>q</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img /> FDATA
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>x</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This snippet is just perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite generic, so will be the answer.

```
var table = document.querySelector("table");

//append the ordered nodes, wrapped in a DocumentFragment
//this will be the last task that will be run, 
//although it's the first command here
table.appendChild(
    //get the rows you want to sort and convert the NodeList into an Array
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tr"))
        //fetch the data you want to sort by.
        .map(row => {
            //return an intermediate-representation that associates
            //your row with the (now cached) data you want to sort by.
            //fetching this data in the sort-function would be way more expensive
            return {
                target: row,
                value: row.querySelector("td").textContent
            }
        });
        //sort
        .sort((a,b) => a.value.localeCompare( b.value )) 
        //concat the rows into a document-fragment
        .reduce((frag, data) => {
            frag.appendChild( data.target );
            return frag;
        }, document.createDocumentFragment())
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think i am able to adapt this to my needs

Comment: @Thomas Beautiful coding. I would do the map function (and reduce too) as follows though `.map(row => ({target: row, value: row.querySelector("td").textContent}))` No need for braces and `return` if you can make it in a single instruction.